# A server program is on an infinite loop. How to check for it?

Tags: c++, loops, gdb, infinite-loop

A server program is on an infinite loop. How to check for it?

My solution:

use GDB to check the values of condition variables that control the loop.

It is ok for small program.

how to do that for large program ?

If the program is not running in GDB, how to detect the endless loop ?

thanks

Comment: Sounds like the halting problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use some form of a [watchdog timer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer). Have the program output a character or touch a file periodically, so if it gets stuck in a loop, a separate process can detect that the watchdog has not been updated and kill/reset the process.

A lot of microcontrollers have this built into the hardware, and they will automatically reset if you don't reset the timer. It's very handy :)

Answer (score 1):

If the program is running on the server you can attach a GDB process to it by giving its pid.

So for example look for the pid of the process using ps:

ps ax | grep server_process

```
3789   ??  S      0:00.58 /usr/bin/server_process
3790   ??  S      0:00.58 /usr/bin/server_process
18002  ??  S      0:00.58 grep server_process
```

You probably want the child:

so use gdb to attach to the running process

```
gdb /usr/bin/server_process 3790
```

.... loads symbols

```
gdb>
```

Happy tracing :)

Of course replace server_process with your program name and the path appropriately :P

Answer (score 1):

Detecting an infinite loop is called the [Halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) which is undecidable.

So in principle there is no sure way to detect it.